# How do I disable an app custom sound on Huawei devices?

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, notifications, huawei-mobile-services

I am building an Android app written in Kotlin.

So whenever I press a button my phone emits a sound (even in silent mode), so that the phone can be found.
It works great on Samsung devices, but on Huawei, if I select a custom app sound -since I can-, this makes the phone emit 2 separate sounds: one is a MediaPlayer notification, and the second one is the ringtone app sound.

Now, I want to disable the latter but there is no documentation regarding Huawei devices specifically. Can anybody help me with it?

I can either disable the custom sound selection or overwrite it programmatically.

Thanks!

Here's my function:

```
 private fun playNotification() {
        val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, soundUri)

        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0)
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f)
        mediaPlayer.start()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the Button widget in the layout?

If you don't want the system ringtone, you can use TextView or Imageview to replace the Button.

```
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="text"
                android:padding="10dp" 
                android:onClick="onClick"/>
```